# Is it possible in Java to return the 401 Unauthorized response code explicitly

Tags: java, web-services, soap, authorization

I am working on a web service. I want to return the `401: Unauthorized` response to the user for invalid credentials.

How do I manually return this response code?

Comment: need more info, are you using servlets, or some framework?

Comment: A 401 error is not an exception, it's a response code.

Comment: @agreco I want to send this as response code. I am using web services.

Comment: Which library are you using for the web service implementation?

Comment: @TechSpellBound. I am using javax.jws.WebService;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

assuming you are using servlets, you would set the http status to 401 using the `setStatus` method:

`httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);`

[HttpServletResponse info](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

Answer (score 20):

For error status codes like 401, use the more specific [sendError()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "your message goes here");
```

This takes care of everything, it sets the status code and also writes the response.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned the following from both [Austin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393574/is-it-possible-in-java-to-return-the-401-unauthorized-response-code-explicitly#14393756) and [Bodgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393574/is-it-possible-in-java-to-return-the-401-unauthorized-response-code-explicitly#21539244) answers, this may save some minutes for someone else looking for this answer.

For me, the correct answer is [Bodgand's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393574/is-it-possible-in-java-to-return-the-401-unauthorized-response-code-explicitly#21539244):

```
httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "your message goes here");
```

The reason is that responses being thrown using the `sendError` method are catched by the `web.xml` filters

So if you had specified at your `web.xml` filter this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/401.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

You will only see that error-page when you use the `sendError` method.