# HttpServletResponse.setIntHeader() not working

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, http-headers

I'm trying to set a custom header on the HttpServletResponse of my Struts 2 action, however it seems to be not producing the desired effect. The response is still being sent with a 200 OK header. Here is my code:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
response.reset();
response.setIntHeader("Unauthorized", 401);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write( jsonString );
```

These are the resulting headers which I see in firebug:

[image: firebug]

So, it seems that while the response headers are being correctly set to 401, that isn't having the desired effect, i.e firebug is still showing the resulting headers as 200 OK. What do I need to do to have firebug show 401 unauthorized as the headers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible in Java to return the 401 Unauthorized response code explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393574/is-it-possible-in-java-to-return-the-401-unauthorized-response-code-explicitly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found it, but it would be preferable to do this instead:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

It amounts to the same thing of course, but it is better to use the constants for the sake of maintainability and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I needed to do `response.setStatus(401);` .